# Starscream not working with inheritance from NSObject

Tags: ios

I'm trying create a class inheritance from NSObject with importing of starscream class. But the websocketDidConnect never is called.

not work!

```
class WebSocketService : NSObject , WebSocketDelegate {

var socket = WebSocket(url: NSURL(scheme: "wss", host:     GlobalUrl.WEB_SOCKET_URI, path: "/ws")!, protocols: ["chat", "superchat"])

override init() {
    super.init()
    socket.delegate = self
    socket.connect()
}
```

When I used from inheritance from UIViewcontroller, it works fine.

```
class WebSocketService : UIViewController , WebSocketDelegate {

var socket = WebSocket(url: NSURL(scheme: "wss", host:     GlobalUrl.WEB_SOCKET_URI, path: "/ws")!, protocols: ["chat", "superchat"])

override init() {
    super.init()
    socket.delegate = self
    socket.connect()
}
```

have any problem if the class is kind of NSObject ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine with NSObject, you just need to implement all the methods of the delegate (they aren't optional in Swift). If you don't get a see websocketDidConnect get called, it is because it didn't connect successfully (probably SSL error or wrong url, etc). Look at the error return in websocketDidDisconnect to figure out what went wrong.

```
class WebSocketService : NSObject , WebSocketDelegate {

var socket = WebSocket(url: NSURL(scheme: "wss", host: GlobalUrl.WEB_SOCKET_URI, path: "/ws")!, protocols: ["chat", "superchat"])

override init() {
    super.init()
    socket.delegate = self
    socket.connect()
}

func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocket) {

}
func websocketDidDisconnect(socket: WebSocket, error: NSError?) {

}
func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocket, text: String) {

}
func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocket, data: NSData) {

}
```

}

Comment: I had implemented all the methods of the delegate like example above and any of them isn't called. I have called the WebSocketService class on the main ViewController like that var socket = WebSocketService()

Comment: Are you keeping the var socket as a instance variable? If isn't an instance variable and only created for that stack/function scope then it will get deallocated immediately. See this for more info: https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream/issues/120#issuecomment-142391496

Comment: It's working! Thanks for the explanation @daltoniam.